# In glsl struct do I need to do padding for vec2 types (using layout std430)

Tags: glsl, compute-shader

I have glsl code:

```
struct PStruct{
  vec2 P1;
  vec2 P2;
}
layout(std430) buffer MyList 
  {
    PStruct list[];
  }
```

Do i need to do padding after each vec2 P1 declaration to get proper alignment, in C language:

```
struct PStruct{
  float P1[2];
  float padding1[2];
  float P2[2];
  float padding2[2];
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is the C data structure? The difference between the `std140` and the `std340` layout is, that the the base alignment and stride of arrays is not rounded up to a multiple of the base alignment of a `vec4`, which is 16 bytes. `PStruct` has a size of 16 bytes, so there is no difference.

Comment: i am mapping C-language structure in CPU memory to same structure in GPU memory. I am asking if i need to add padding1 and padding2 or it is unecessary

Comment: If the data type which corresponds to `vec2` in C is something like `float[2]`, then you don't need any padding. Note, in C the size of a type `struct PStruct{ float P1[2], P2[2]; }` is 16.

Comment: thank you. vec2 type is defined in my code as float[2] so yes this answers my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i need to do padding after each vec2 P1 declaration to get proper alignment, in C language:

No, you can't do that.

In GLSL the size of the struct `PStruct` is 16 bytes and `P1` and `P2` are aligned to 8 bytes:

```
struct PStruct{
    vec2 P1;
    vec2 P2;
}
```

This causes that `buffer MyList` will be tightly packed

```
layout(std430) buffer MyList 
{
    PStruct list[];
}
```

This corresponds to the following structure in C, which has a size of 16 bytes, `P1` and `P2` have a size of 8 bytes and are aligned to 4 bytes:

```
struct PStruct{
    float P1[2];
    float P2[2];
}
```

---

For the explanation see the rules 2, 4 and 9 of the `std140` respectively `std340` layout:

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout; page 144](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> ....
>
> 2. If the member is a two- or four-component vector with components consuming N basic machine units, the base alignment is 2N or 4N, respectively.
>
> ...
>
> 4. If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment and array stride are set to match the base alignment of a single array element, according to rules (1), (2), and (3), and rounded up to the base alignment of a `vec4`. The array may have padding at the end; the base offset of the member following the array is rounded up to the next multiple of the base alignment.
>
> ...
>
> 9. If the member is a structure, the base alignment of the structure is N, where N is the largest base alignment value of any of its members, and rounded up to the base alignment of a `vec4`.
>
> ...
>
> When using the `std430` storage layout, shader storage blocks will be laid out in buffer storage identically to uniform and shader storage blocks using the `std140` layout, except that the base alignment and stride of arrays of scalars and vectors in rule 4 and of structures in rule 9 are not rounded up a multiple of the base alignment of a `vec4`.